# Pressing 0 isn't putting me in camera view like the tutorial but instead inside of the object

Tags: rendering

In 37:04 of this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdMrWxOnqnE&t=1973s he presses <kbd>0</kbd> to go into camera view (with the box around it).

The problem is when I click <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> it shows a zoomed in top down view of the object, so I'm on the inside of it and not the camera view.

What is causing this? I tried *Emulate Numpad* and that didn't fix it.

Is there an option enabled I missed?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your blender. My guess right now is you may have multiple cameras and not realize it or your binds got messed up.

Comment: @MrCalamari It's most likely the object he's inside has been made the active camera.

Answer (score 1):

When you switch to camera view and then you are inside of an object looking top down, you have accidentally made that object the active camera by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

To get back your actual camera, you can either select the (or one of the) camera object(s) in the *3D Viewport* and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to switch back from the other object.

Or you can click on the green camera symbol behind the camera's name in the *Outliner* to make it the active camera again, it will indicate it by highlighting the symbol afterwards:

[image: active cam in outliner]